# Mapping template for new AWS Gateway UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

How do I access the mapping template section in the new AWS Gateway UI? Have they removed it?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use a proxy configuration, you cannot add/edit mapping
   template.
2. If you are NOT using proxy configuration, first save the method with
   the integration type and come back to "Integration Request" to add
   the mapping template.